# What is the most effective validation method on Flask?

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, flask-mongoengine

First of all, I try to make an Rest-API with Flask MongoEngine. I create a model which is;

```
class Project(db.Document):

    name = db.StringField(validation=validate_project_name)
    created_at = db.DateTimeField()
    updated_at = db.DateTimeField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.created_at:
            self.created_at = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.updated_at = datetime.datetime.now()
        return super(Project, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and I also created a Form ;

```
ProjectForm = model_form(Project, exclude=["created_at", "updated_at"])
```

and also the custom validation is ;

```
def validate_project_name(name, min=5, max=25):
    if len(name) <= min or len(name) >= max:
        raise ValidationError(
            f"Proje adı en az {min} en fazla {max} karakter olabilir!"
        )
    return True
```

I want to validate with ProjectFrom when i send the data which I get from request body that's why i prepare that code ;

```
@project.route("/create", methods=["POST"])
def create_project():
    data = MultiDict(request.json)
    form = ProjectForm(data, meta={"csrf": False})
    if form.validate():
        if Project(name=form.data["name"]).save():
            ## will take create action
            return True
    else:
        return Response({form.errors}, status=400)
```

It returns true when i request but when i change de data on request.body it still returns true where do i mistake can someone help me and explain the logic. Or Should i create a middleware for the validation also i tried that. and i created something. But i don't know is it the best way.
Thanks in advance...

Middleware that i tried to validate data;

```
def creation_project_validation(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == "POST":
            data = request.json
            if data.get("name") is None:
                return Response({"Name is required field!"}, status=400)

            if validate_project_name(data.get("name")):
                return Response(
                    {"Karakter uzunluğu istenilen şekilde değil!"}, status=400
                )
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            Response("Method not allowed", status=405)

    return decorated_function
```